# What is a SIP button?

Tags: windows-mobile

I'm using a toolkit by RESCO and the keyboard has a property "AutoHideSipButton"

There is nothing in the documentation that tells me what a SIP button is.

I did a google search and found reference to a SIP Button in Windows Mobile, but every link assumes the viewer already knows what it is.

So.
What is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SIP, as Brandon suggests, is the Soft Input Panel.  On WinMo there is a button on the main, lower toolbar that when clicked brings up a menu of which SIPs are available and allows you to show them.  The AutoHideSipButton doesn't show or hide the SIP itself, it simply shows/hides the button that allows a SIP to be selected.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It likely means [Soft Input Panel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_Input_Panel), which in your case is probably just the onscreen keyboard.

So the button toggles the keyboard visibility.